# Change isolation level in command line shell in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, isolation-level

I would like to change the isolation level in SQLite. Can I do this in the command line shell?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, the isolation level can be changed with [PRAGMA read_uncommitted](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_read_uncommitted), but this applies only to database connections in [shared-cache mode](http://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html), which are not used by the `sqlite3` command-line shell.

For practical purposes, [SQLite transactions always are completely serialized](http://sqlite.org/transactional.html) (because [there is no write concurrency](http://sqlite.org/faq.html#q5) in the first place).